# latex table align decimal, stars, column width

Tags: columns, dcolumn

I am trying to align my columns on the decimal points. I'd like the column widths to be equal. I believe a possible answer is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37871/format-spacing-for-correlation-table-any-statistical-table), but I am really struggling to implement. Any thoughts?

Note: I need to have the asterisks in the same column. In other words, I cannot rely on `-0.470&***`. I should be able to wrap asterisks in other code, however (e.g., `-0.470^{***}`) if essential.

```
\documenttype{report}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllllll}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\ 
  \hline
  1 &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
  2 &  0.47*** &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
  3 &  0.28* &  0.24* &  &  &  &   \\ 
  4 &  0.14 & -0.03 & -0.08 &  &  &    \\ 
  5 & -0.28* & -0.22 & -0.11 & -0.38*** &  &    \\ 
  6 &  0.14 & -0.02 &  0.02 &  0.23* & -0.02 &    \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The closest I've come is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{L}{@{}l@{}} % a left column with no intercolumn space on either side
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % shorthand macro for column headings

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
%\begin{tabular}{rllllll}
\begin{tabular}{LS@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}S@{}}
  \hline
 \mc{} &  \mc{1} &  \mc{2} &  \mc{3} &  \mc{4} &  \mc{5} &  \mc{6} \\ 
  \hline
  1 &  &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
  2 &  0.47*** &  &  &  &  &   \\ 
  3 &  0.28* &  0.24* &  &  &  &   \\ 
  4 &  0.14 & -0.03 & -0.08 &  &  &    \\ 
  5 & -0.28* & -0.22 & -0.11 & -0.38*** &  &    \\ 
  6 &  0.14 & -0.02 &  0.02 &  0.23* & -0.02 &    \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But notice (a) the space between -0.28 and * and (b) varying column widths.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can play with the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l
                S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]
                S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]
                S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]
                S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]
                S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]
                S[table-format = -1.2,table-space-text-post = {*}]}
  \hline
           & {1}     & {2}   & {3}   & {4}      & {5}   & {6} \\
  \hline
  1       &         &       &       &          &       &     \\
  2       & 0.47*** &       &       &          &       &     \\
  3       & 0.28*   & 0.24* &       &          &       &     \\
  4       & 0.14    & -0.03 & -0.08 &          &       &     \\
  5       & -0.28*  & -0.22 & -0.11 & -0.38*** &       &     \\
  6       & 0.14    & -0.02 & 0.02  & 0.23*    & -0.02 &     \\
   \hline                                                    
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]